# LCG code in matlab

Tags: matlab, lcg

I have written this code :

```
for i=1:m-1
x(i+1)=mod(a*x(i)+c,m)
x(i)=x(i+1)
end
```

But I don't know how to write lcg as a function that generates random numbers.

LCG is a linear congruential generator which is one of the oldest and best-known pseudorandom number generator algorithms. The generator is defined by the recurrence relation:

```
  Xn+1 =(aXn + c) mod m
```

,and I want to write a function for this relation.

Comment: What's LCG? What's the desired output?

Comment: I have edited my question. @Dev-iL

Comment: What do you want different from the code you currently have? Do you simply want it in the form of a function, or do you want to make it generate the subsequent random number on each call?

Comment: Did you look in the File Exchange? Maybe you can get some hits from the following submissions (and maybe others): https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47426-linear-congruential-random-number-generator/content/usage_RNG.m , https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46129-grogono-linear-congruent-random-number-generator/content//grogono.m.